# Interpret learning curve results

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions, accuracy

I leveraged a pre-trained VGG network for a binary classification problem and am tuning with its hyper-parameters. I have generated curves for each setting (both accuracy and loss) below. I am unsure of which model would perform best.

[image: Learning curves for a pre-trained VGG model under 4 different hyper-parameter sets]

In my code, I save the best model weights (i.e. meaning the epoch at which the validation accuracy is highest), so Idk whether to go with the model that provides the highest validation accuracy (the 2nd and 4th ones) or the one that has the nicest curve (the 1st one). What would be a decision-making process you would take?